# Facebook Graph API Slow for Larger Data Calls

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is what I am doing in PHP to get access to a bunch of group posts on Facebook.  I'm then implementing a search function to search these posts.

```
        $url2 = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'. $group_id . '/feed' . '?limit=30&access_token=' . $_SESSION['access_token'] ;

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url2");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $json = curl_exec($ch);
        $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

So I broke it down and just found that putting the graph url into my browser yields a slow response.  Limit set to 30 is ok, but up it to 300 and it is slow, up it to 1,000 and it crawls.

I've looked into paging but I would like to grab a large amount of data so I can search it. Caching really wouldn't work because it still takes so long to load that initial data.

Is there anyway to speed this up or am I stuck at the limitation of the Facebook Graph API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could batch your requests so that you only set the curl once for the batched request, instead of looking through numerous curls http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/03/17/batch-requests-in-graph-api/

```
    $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
    $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET"; 
    $my_url = "YOUR_URL";

    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

    if(empty($code)) {
      $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url);

      echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
    }

    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

    $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $batched_request = '[{"method":"GET","relative_url":"me"},' . '{"method":"GET","relative_url":"me/friends?limit=50"}]';

    $post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . "?batch=" . $batched_request . "&access_token=" . $access_token . "&method=post";
    echo $post_url;

    $post = file_get_contents($post_url);
    echo '<p>Response: <pre>' . $post . '</pre></p>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CURLOPT_ENCODING` per the documentation:

> The contents of the "Accept-Encoding: " header. This enables decoding
>   of the response. Supported encodings are "identity", "deflate", and
>   "gzip". If an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all
>   supported encoding types is sent.

This way cURL will be telling Facebook, *"hey I understand compressed data, please send me compressed data"*.

```
$url2 = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'. $group_id . '/feed' . '?limit=30&access_token=' . $_SESSION['access_token'] ;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, ''); // enable compression, keep empty to send all supported types
$json = curl_exec($ch);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

Comment: This didn't seem to help.  What compression is FB using?

Comment: @350_Design it could vary depending on the HTTP `Accept-Encoding` header sent by the browser or in this case cURL. If you run **ONLY** the above code just by itself limited to 300 is it slow? If not then it may likely be the PHP code you are using to process the response that is the bottleneck.

Comment: Yeah anyway I run it, it is slow.  If I output the url variable and paste that into the browser it is slow.  Usually 5 to 10 seconds.

Comment: @350_Design, what exactly are you trying to search for and in what? You might be able to simplify the request to narrow down the response.

Comment: Name, time posted, picture, post content, & comments.

Comment: Is there a way to only pull that information with the graph URL?

Comment: Yes, there is: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/selecting-results/ You should try it in the Graph API Explorer, it’s easy clicking it together there: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer